# Remove element that is not in .css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I will try to describe my question in as much detail as possible, since this is the first time I encounter such a problem and could not find a description on the Internet.

On my site, the user can select a time range. For this I am using the "react-advanced-datetimerange-picker" library. But I would like to make my own style.
I need to remove the inscription "Custom Range" along with the blue background (photo below). The markup shows where the styles of this component are written - rangeButton0. But this component is not in the .css file that comes with the library.

[image]

Basically, I need to remove rangeButton0. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Did you try adding css of display none with important on id selector rangeButton0 in your css for this component?

Comment: @ShahinNazer No, I have not tried this option. Can you describe in more detail?

Comment: in your css try what @ShahinNazer said => #rangeButton0 {display: none !important;} that may override any css and the button will disappear. If so, you know you can modify the button with css rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your css, you can add

```
#rangeButton0 {
display: none !important;
}
```

This should override any existing css on that element and remove it from the dom